# Ansible Multi Group Dynamic Inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm new to Ansible so be patient. I was trying to create a dynamic inventory using Ansible's dynamic inventory pluging. In particular I'm using hcloud plugin to interface with Hetzner's API.
What I'd like to do is create 3 groups : databases, nfs, k8s.

All servers have already been tag as follows :

- app=mysql for mySQL database servers
- app=nfs for NFS servers
- app=k8s for k8s cluster servers (workers and masters)

To say the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/hetzner/hcloud/hcloud_inventory.html#parameters) are lacking is using an euphemism. I've tried using label_selector as follows with no success:

```
plugin: hcloud
token: hehe
groups:
    databases:
        label_selector: app=mysql
    nfs:
        label_selector: app=nfs
    k8s:
        label_selector: app=k8s
```

This indeed results in the creation of 3+ groups :

- all

  - databases
  - nfs
  - k8s
  - ungrouped
  - hcloud

yet all groups contain all hosts, regardless of the label.
So my questions are :

1. Assuming I'm using something like keyed_groups, which "Add hosts to group based on the values of a variable.", where can I find accepted variables?In the example they use 'location', 'image_os_flavor' and 'status' but I haven't found a list of accepted variable names that I could use.
2. How could I implement a dynamic Inventory that reaches the previously explained goal?
3. Is it possible to add group variables in dynamically generated inventories?

Thanks a lot to everyone, let me know how to improve my question as well.

Comment: Did you simply try with `key: app` in `keyed_groups`? If this work, the only drawback is that your `databases` groups will be named `mysql`. Regarding your 3rd question: simply add a e.g. `group_vars/k8s.yml` file with the vars for `k8s` group in the same directory as your dynamic inventory config file.

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks, yea in the end using key: labels.app worked. Whats bothering me is that I cant find any docs relative to how keyed_groups and such works. Do you know if there is any reference anywhere?

Comment: What about the one you linked from which I made my recommendation ? ;) As I understand it, you can use any available variable as a key to create a group.

Comment: @Zeitounator There they simply state : "Add hosts to group based on the values of a variable." without ever specifying what is meant by variable. The fact that 'labels'  was a valid variable is intuitive since Hetzner allows for labels to be added to servers but nowhere in that doc have I found a detailed list of what this variables cloud be. Well thanks again anyway <3

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
groups:
    databases: labels.app == 'mysql'
    nfs: labels.app == 'nfs'
    k8s: labels.app == 'k8s'
```

The documentation is here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/constructed_inventory.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).